# How to extend express object using typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

When I compiled a typescript project I don't see express import `import {Request, Response}`. Now I am trying to use `require` but not sure how to extend the express object and use `req` and `res`. Any help will be appreciated.

index.ts

```
// import {Request, Response} from 'express';
import express = require('express');
import * as sdkStore from "../../common/sdk-store";


export function getInfo(req: Request, res: Response) {

    var app = sdkStore.getSdkInstance(req.body.client);
    app.Payment.Info(req.body, function (result) {
        res.send(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with `import { Request, Response }`?

Comment: not sure i dont see that line in compiled version of index.js

Comment: Do you have @types/express installed?

Comment: yes @types/express is installed

Answer (score 0):

I am using the same strategy to use `Request` & `Response` from `express` module.

This is how I am doing it (check parameters of `getTemples` method)-

> Typescript

```
import * as express from "express";
import { Response as ApiResponse } from "../models/response.model";
import { TempleProvider } from "../providers/temple.provider";

export namespace TempleFacade {

    export function getTemples(req: express.Request, res: express.Response, next: express.NextFunction): void {
        let apiResponse: ApiResponse<any> = new ApiResponse();
        TempleProvider.getTemples()
            .then((response: Array<any>) => {
                apiResponse.data = response;
                res.json(apiResponse);
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                apiResponse.data = null;
                apiResponse.status = false;
                apiResponse.messages = error;
                res.json(apiResponse);
            });
    }
}
```

> Compiled Javascript

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
const response_model_1 = require("../models/response.model");
const temple_provider_1 = require("../providers/temple.provider");
var TempleFacade;
(function (TempleFacade) {
    function getTemples(req, res, next) {
        let apiResponse = new response_model_1.Response();
        temple_provider_1.TempleProvider.getTemples()
            .then((response) => {
            apiResponse.data = response;
            res.json(apiResponse);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
            apiResponse.data = null;
            apiResponse.status = false;
            apiResponse.messages = error;
            res.json(apiResponse);
        });
    }
    TempleFacade.getTemples = getTemples;
})(TempleFacade = exports.TempleFacade || (exports.TempleFacade = {}));
//# sourceMappingURL=temple.facade.js.map
```

I hope this helps :)